# Find all objects with list attribute element that exist in another list

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-6

I have two lists.  One is of type AppUser that comes from the database and the other is of type customer that is passed in as a parameter.  Here are the class definitions.

```
public class AppUser
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<Customer> customers{get;set;}
}

public class Customer
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<User> users{get;set;}
}
```

I am attempting to create an API endpoint that will allow a person to pass in a list of Customers and get back all the unique users in the database for that list of customers.  So what I have is a list attribute for the users that needs to be compared to a list of customers being passed in to the API.  I the following code but it does not work.  I am somewhat new to linq so am really confused.

```
var joinUsers = repoUsers.Join(
   customers, 
   uObj => uObj, 
   cObj => cObj, 
   (uObj, cObj) => uObj
);
```

repoUsers is my list of users from the database with each having a customers list as an attribute.

customers is my list of customers passed into my API.

How can I join my repoUsers object using it's customers list attribute compared to the customers list passed in and return the repoUsers that match a customer in the customers list?

Comment: Seems like an unusual thing to need to do.  If that's really what is needed, I think I'd use the brute force method - run through each user, start comparing customers and quit at the first mismatch (assuming it can't be a subset - that isn't clearly defined).  There may be a nice query to do it, but nothing off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project your input to an `IEnumerable` of IDs then use the `Contains` method on the `Customer.Id`. Finish up by using `SelectMany` to aggregate each customer’s `Users` property then `Distinct` to remove duplicates

```
var cutomerIDs = customers.Select( c => c.Id );

var usersQuery = dbContext.Customers
    .Where( c => customerIDs.Contains( c.Id ) )
    .SelectMany( c => c.Users )
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: You are a life saver.  Thank you Moho!   Seems so easy now that I look at it but I was completely wrapped around the axle on it.